# Replacing characters within a text with regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace few characters from a text. These characters maybe from start or end or it may be in middle. The problem is that it hasn't any white space at starting or ending. 
For example i want to replace "text" from this text with, for instance, "abc".

*input:*
 **Thisisatextbox**

*output:*
**Thisisaabcbox**

I tried this code so far.

```
Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, @"\w[text]", "abc");
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following.. `[ ]` has special meaning (character class) in regex:

```
Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, @"text", "abc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a simple Replace function work? I don't believe Regex is required.
Try this :

```
string oldText = "Thisisatextbox";
string newText = oldText.Replace("text", "abc");
```

I believe this would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, @"\w*(text)\w*", "abc");
```

Use parentheses to capture the text you want to replace.

[] describes a character class. So, if you put [text] it will take **ONE** character from "t", "x", "e" to search for a possible match.